# Swagger: Custom example JSON request body

Tags: java, spring, api, swagger, springfox

I have one question about request body example in Swagger.

This is my whole User entity example:

```
{
"id": 14,
"firstname": "fghfgh",
"lastname": "fghfghfgh",
"email": "customer",
"password": "pass",
"roles": [
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "customer"
    }
]
```

}

I have register method, which use User Entity as parameter:

```
    @ApiOperation(value = "Registering seller", response = User.class)
@PostMapping(value = "/seller/register")
public User addSeller(@RequestBody @Valid User user){
    return userService.addSeller(user);
}
```

I use my register endpoint with User entity without id and roles fields (this fields are added in backend)

Example register request body:

```
{
    "firstname": "345345",
    "lastname": "fghfghfgh",
    "email": "customer3",
    "password": "pass"
}
```

In swagger my example request body according to the parameter is whole User entity:
[image]

but I want to get in Swagger request body example without id and roles fields, how to do it in proper way? I must create for example UserRegister class with firstname,lastname,email and password fields and use it as register method paramter? Or there's other option with using User entity as parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hide the `id` and `roles` in User entity using `@ApiModelProperty(hidden=true)` feature, not sure if this is what you wanted, but you can try this.